# if statement in js not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

My `if (i>0)` statement here is not working, any advice why not?

http://jsfiddle.net/qup2R/

I want it to prevent my inital form box from reacting to the 
`$('.remove').click(function() if`i = 0`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var i = 0;
      $('document').ready(function () {
        if (i > 0) {
          $('.remove').click(function () {
            i--;
            $(this).closest('form').remove();
          });
        }
        $('.clickme').click(function () {
          if (i < 5) {
            i++;
            $(".form1").last().clone(true, true).appendTo("body");
          } else {
            $(".form1")
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <h3>Invite your friends</h3>

    <form class="form1">
      <input id="email" name="email" />
      <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <a class="clickme" href="#">Add</a>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your remove events are defined in the code above? I am sure they are not

Comment: What is happening? Is it always triggering at i=0? Is it never getting called?

Comment: Next time, have some mercy and format your question in such a way that one can read it without getting a headache...

Comment: If you don't want to remove those initial elements -which is, I think what you want-, don't give them the `remove` and `clickme` classes in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use statements inside click function and add logical operators like `&&` for getting accurate results.

```
 $('.remove').click(function () {
     if (i > 0 && i < 5 ) {
         i--;
         $(this).closest('form').remove();
     }
 });

 $('.clickme').click(function () {
     if (i < 5 && i > 0) {
          i++;
          $(".form1").last().clone(true, true).appendTo("body");
     }
 });
```

Comment: hey barlas you are right thx on putting the if inside the function, no need to switch the   i++; with  i--;  ---> thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at your code:

```
    if (i > 0) {
      $('.remove').click(function () {
        i--;
        $(this).closest('form').remove();
      });
    }
```

This will bind an event handler to all `.remove` elements only when `i > 0`. At DOM ready, `i == 0` so the handler is *never bound*. What you're actually trying to achieve is checking if `i > 0` *when a `.remove` is clicked*. Thus, that check needs to be *inside* the handler, not outside.

```
    $('.remove').click(function () {
      if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        $(this).closest('form').remove();
      }
    });
```

**EDIT 1:** Okay, it seems like you're after something else. You want your first `form` to not be removed from the page, since then you can't add new forms any longer. The problem is that your `i` represents the *amount of forms on the page* (minus 1, since you start with 1 form already in the HTML) as opposed to the *insertion index*. There are a few ways to get around this:

- Give the first form an extra class and remove that class in cloned forms. You can then check whether the clicked `.remove` is a child of a `form` with that class with something like `$(this).closest('form').hasClass('firstForm')`.
- Manually add the `.remove` link only to dynamically generated forms. You could build a template element stored it in a variable and then append clones to new forms.
- Check the index of the `form` whose `.remove` was clicked. If it's the first, don't remove it.

**EDIT 2:** All right, so you don't actually care whether the first form is removed, you just want to ensure that at least one of the forms is still on the page. That's why you were keeping track of the amount of forms. Seriously, truly confusing. It'd help if you'd at least explain what your reasoning is for your code, commenting is not an afterthought!

Anyhow, you should have enough on my initial fix (above the edits).

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what you are describing in your EDIT, but the code does solve my main problem (the main form can't be removed when i == 0)

Comment: @IanO.S. It does, I overcomplicated it a bit. In my first edit, the first form gets special treatment so that it cannot be removed. In my my previous and barlas's solution, it doesn't matter which form remains - as long as there's at least one remaining.

Answer (score 0):

change the jquery to this and try

```
$('document').ready(function () {
       var i = 0;
      $('.remove').click(function () {
        if (i > 0) {
          i--;
        $(this).closest('form').remove();
        }
      });

    $('.clickme').click(function () {
      if (i < 5) {
        i++;
        $(".form1").last().clone(true, true).appendTo("body");
      } else {
        $(".form1")
      }
    });
  });
```